# Javascript Reference Loops When Closing a Tab?

Tags: javascript

I am getting my feet into Javascript, and I am concerned about memory leakage as I was trying to do Object Oriented sort of programming in there.

If I do the following:

```
function ObjectOne() {
  this.setRelation = function(objectTwo) {
    this.objectTwo = objectTwo;
  }
}

function ObjectTwo() {
  var self = this;
  self.setRelation = function(objectOne) {
    this.objectOne = objectOne;  
    objectOne.setRelation(self);
  }
}

var objOne = new ObjectOne();
var objTwo = new ObjectTwo();
objTwo.setRelation(objOne);
```

... Will this create a reference loop in Javascript which can potentially lead to memory leak?

Second question is, will this reference loop be eliminated when you close a browser's tab?

Comment: So basically you are afraid of `var obj1 = {}, obj2 = {obj1: obj1}; obj1.obj2 = obj2;`?

Comment: *"Will this create a reference loop"* - Yes. *"...which can potentially lead to memory leak?"* - No.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was basically afraid of. I repped both of you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

> As of 2012, all modern browsers ship a mark-and-sweep garbage-collector.

Mark-and-sweep garbage-collectors can handle reference cycles.

The new [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) type takes great care to avoid weak-reference loops becoming hard by using [*Ephemerons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeron).  See https://vimeo.com/9965316

Comment: Thanks a lot! Explains a lot!